# MySQL GROUP BY CASE error

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

I'm trying to quantize my query output using GROUP BY CASE statement.
I tried CASE in SELECT section, in GROUP BY section, in both, but still get **"Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function."**

Here's my code (with CASE in both sections)

```
SELECT 
case when BBsum.sum <= 9999 then '<10K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 10999 then '<11K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 11999 then '<12K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 12999 then '<13K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 13999 then '<14K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 14999 then '<15K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 15999 then '<16K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 16999 then '<17K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 17999 then '<18K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 18999 then '<19K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 19999 then '<20K'
    else '20K+' end as sum, 
avg(sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'INSTALLMENT_LOAN' then C.paid_amount end)/sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'INSTALLMENT_LOAN' then C.initial_amount end)) as IL_RR,
avg(sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'PAYDAY_LOAN' then C.paid_amount end)/sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'PAYDAY_LOAN' then C.initial_amount end)) as PDL_RR,
avg(sum(C.paid_amount)/sum(C.initial_amount)) as RR
FROM 
credit C
left join (select BB.borrower_id id, sum(BB.points) sum from borrower_bonus BB
where BB.type = 'CHARGE'
group by bb.borrower_id) BBsum on C.borrower_id = BBsum.id
where C.status IN ('EXPIRED', 'COMPLETED','SOLD')
group by case when BBsum.sum <= 9999 then '<10K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 10999 then '<11K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 11999 then '<12K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 12999 then '<13K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 13999 then '<14K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 14999 then '<15K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 15999 then '<16K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 16999 then '<17K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 17999 then '<18K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 18999 then '<19K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 19999 then '<20K'
    else '20K+' end
order by sum DESC
```

I suspect that i have to do something more simple to achieve what I want (split RR averages by cohorts of received bonuses)

Comment: You are nesting aggregate function `avg(sum(`. MySQL doesnt allow that

Comment: Dont use 'sum' as an alias name for a column. It might be confused by the code for the function sum. Try something like sumOfBB. Even if the mysql engine happens to let it pass, its bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting aggregate function, which MySQL doesnt allow.

This is probably what you want:

```
SELECT 
case when BBsum.sum <= 9999 then '<10K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 10999 then '<11K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 11999 then '<12K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 12999 then '<13K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 13999 then '<14K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 14999 then '<15K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 15999 then '<16K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 16999 then '<17K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 17999 then '<18K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 18999 then '<19K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 19999 then '<20K'
    else '20K+' end as sum, 
sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'INSTALLMENT_LOAN' then C.paid_amount end)
   /sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'INSTALLMENT_LOAN' then C.initial_amount end) as IL_RR,
sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'PAYDAY_LOAN' then C.paid_amount end)
   /sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'PAYDAY_LOAN' then C.initial_amount end) as PDL_RR,
sum(C.paid_amount)/sum(C.initial_amount) as RR
FROM 
credit C
left join (
    select BB.borrower_id id, sum(BB.points) sum 
    from borrower_bonus BB
    where BB.type = 'CHARGE'
    group by bb.borrower_id
) BBsum on C.borrower_id = BBsum.id
where C.status IN ('EXPIRED', 'COMPLETED','SOLD')
group by case when BBsum.sum <= 9999 then '<10K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 10999 then '<11K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 11999 then '<12K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 12999 then '<13K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 13999 then '<14K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 14999 then '<15K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 15999 then '<16K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 16999 then '<17K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 17999 then '<18K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 18999 then '<19K'
    when BBsum.sum <= 19999 then '<20K'
    else '20K+' end
order by sum DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to watch your join you are trying to only calculate the values for BB members with charge accounts but because of the left join, rows in the Credit table without a 'CHARGE' row in the borrower_bonus table are coming back null populated and then getting grouped into the averages. So you are calculating the average for ALL bonus accounts not just Charge accounts. An inner join will ensure ONLY charge account are getting averaged.

```
SELECT -- SELECT THE AVERAGES
    CASE 
        WHEN BBSum.pntSum = 21 THEN '20K+'
        ELSE CONCAT( '<', BBSum.pntSum, '+' )
    END AS AccountType,
    AVG(BBSum.RR),
    AVG(BBSum.IL_RR),
    AVG(BBSum.PDL_RR)
FROM
(
    SELECT  --FIND THE RR, PDL_RR and IL_RR for each account. 
        Credit.paid_amount / Credit.initial_amount AS RR,
        CASE WHEN Credit.finance_type = 'INSTALLMENT_LOAN' THEN RR ELSE 0 END AS IL_RR,
        CASE WHEN Credit.finance_type = 'PAYDAY_LOAN'      THEN RR ELSE 0 END AS PDL_RR
    FROM 
        Credit 
    WHERE
        Credit.status IN ('EXPIRED', 'COMPLETED','SOLD')
        AND Credit.finance_type IN ('INSTALLMENT_LOAN', 'PAYDAY_LOAN')
) AS C
INNER JOIN -- get all credit lines with corresponding borrowers rows. 
(
    SELECT  -- Find the CHARGE account and their grouping
        BB.borrower_id AS id 
      , CASE 
            WHEN SUM(BB.points) <= 9999 THEN 10
            WHEN SUM(BB.points) <= 19999 THEN FLOOR(SUM(BB.points)) / 1000 ) + 1
            ELSE 21
        END AS pntSum
    FROM
        borrower_bonus AS BB
    WHERE 
        BB.type = 'CHARGE'
    GROUP BY
        BB.borrower_id
) as BBSum
ON  
    C.Borrower_id = BBSum.id
GROUP BY 
    BBSum.pntSum
ORDER BY
    BBSum.pntSum DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion on how to write the query.  I think GurV identified the problem correctly:

```
SELECT bbgroup,
       (sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'INSTALLMENT_LOAN' then C.paid_amount end) /
        sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'INSTALLMENT_LOAN' then C.initial_amount end)
       ) as IL_RR,
       (sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'PAYDAY_LOAN' then C.paid_amount end) /
        sum(CASE when C.finance_type = 'PAYDAY_LOAN' then C.initial_amount end)
       ) as PDL_RR,
       (sum(C.paid_amount) / sum(C.initial_amount)) as RR
FROM credit C left join
     (select BB.borrower_id, sum(BB.points) as points_sum,
             (case when sum(BB.points) <= 9999 then '<10K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 10999 then '<11K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 11999 then '<12K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 12999 then '<13K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 13999 then '<14K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 14999 then '<15K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 15999 then '<16K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 16999 then '<17K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 17999 then '<18K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 18999 then '<19K'
                   when sum(BB.points) <= 19999 then '<20K'
                   else '20K+'
              end) as bbgroup 
      from borrower_bonus BB
      where BB.type = 'CHARGE'
      group by bb.borrower_id
     ) BBsum
     on C.borrower_id = BBsum.borrower_id
where C.status IN ('EXPIRED', 'COMPLETED','SOLD')
group by bbgroup
order by bbgroup DESC;
```

Putting a complicated `case` statement in one place really helps maintainability and readability.  I would also change the conditions to match the descriptions:

```
             (case when sum(BB.points) < 10000 then '<10K'
                   when sum(BB.points) < 11000 then '<11K'
                   . . .
```

However, you might have specific business rules for using the 999 version.