# Why hive is asking for my variable in group by? Simple case when

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hue

When I run the hive query bellow, I receive the following error: Error while compiling statement:
`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: line 8:13 Expression not in GROUP BY key '50000'`

Hive Query:

```
SELECT 
    202106 as ANOMES,
    count(wrin_agctd) as QTDETransacoes,
    tipo_transacao,
    cod_cate_cont,
    wrin_nterm,
    case 
        when wrin_valor<50000 then '<500'
        when wrin_valor<100000 then '<1000'
        when wrin_valor<150000 then '<1500'
        when wrin_valor<200000 then '<2000'
    end as test
FROM 
    ghp00468.raultav_saque_conta_salario_tecban_202106
WHERE
    tipo_transacao="SAQUE_TECBAN" and
    tipo_transacao="CONSULTA_TECBAN"
GROUP BY 
    tipo_transacao,
    cod_cate_cont,
    wrin_nterm;
```

Where and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your case statement. The column `test` is not in the group by statement.  You should add your case statement to the group by, or handle it external to the groupby.  [Here's a similar question that someone answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417472/mysql-group-by-case-error)

Comment: It's working now!